# How to override a package method in Django?

Tags: python, django, overriding

I'm trying to override a parent class method that I've installed via **pip**. But, the problem is that I'm not sure how my overridden class will be called so that it will use my method instead of parent class method. This is the method I'm trying to override:

```
class OIDCAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
def verify_claims(self, claims):
        """Verify the provided claims to decide if authentication should be allowed."""

        # Verify claims required by default configuration
        scopes = self.get_settings('OIDC_RP_SCOPES', 'openid email')
        if 'email' in scopes.split():
            return 'email' in claims

        LOGGER.warning('Custom OIDC_RP_SCOPES defined. '
                       'You need to override `verify_claims` for custom claims verification.')

        return True
```

And my overridden method is :

**models.py**

```
from mozilla_django_oidc.auth import OIDCAuthenticationBackend

class MyOIDCAB(OIDCAuthenticationBackend):
    def verify_claims(self, claims):
         return True
```

I've written this on models.py according to some docs I read for overriding but I'm not sure where should I actually write this.

then trying to call it from my view functions like this:

**views.py**

```
from myapp import MyOIDCAB
```

but then I got this error:

> ```
> from myapp import MyOIDCAB
> ```
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'MyOIDCAB'

I'm not sure I'm calling it in the right way or wrong?
My project structure is:

```
myproject
myapp
templates
manage.py
```

From the package site, they call it in the template like this:

```
 <a href="{% url 'oidc_authentication_init'%}">Login</a>
```

Comment: The override is fine, the issue is with importing, see if there is an `__init__.py` in the root of the folder where your `MyOIDCAB` class is declared. You need the `__init__.py` file to be able to import your module.

Comment: my two `__init__.py` files are empty @JosipKolarić

Comment: Is it named `init.py` or `__init__.py`? There is a difference

Comment: it's `__init__.py`

Comment: If they are empty, you can't do `from directory import MyClass` because directory itself doesn't have the class - you need to do `from directory,module import MyClass`. => `from myapp.models import MyOIDCAB`

Comment: @h4z3 `from directory,module` should be `from directory.module`

Comment: Thank you, @Taek. I missed the key but now I can't edit my previous comment...

Comment: thanks that import issue has been solved now, but after running the file, I saw it is still the same, no overriden is working

Answer (score 0):

The class is in models.py file so here's how you should import that :

```
from myapp.models import MyOIDCAB
```